# How do I get R to read in a DAT file using scan() function?

Tags: r, data-mining

I'm using the RGui to read in 10 DAT files for the digits dataset. (One file for each digit)

This is the code I'm using:

```
d0=scan("Zl0d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d1=scan("Zl1d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d2=scan("Zl2d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d3=scan("Zl3d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d4=scan("Zl4d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d5=scan("Zl5d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d6=scan("Zl6d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d7=scan("Zl7d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d8=scan("Zl8d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)
d9=scan("Zl9d.dat",nlines=1000,n=256000)

d=c(d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9)

d=matrix(d,256,10000)
```

But when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : cannot open file 'Zl0d.dat': No such file or directory
```

(I only ran it for the first file for the purpose of asking this but it's the same issue with every file.)

All 10 files are saved in the same directory as this script so I don't know why its saying "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1):

If you run a script that is located in a specific folder, it is not a given your working directory of the current R session is as well in that directory. You can set the working directory with the `setwd` function. You can check your current working directory with the `getwd` function.

Other methods for setting the working directory could be (but are not limited to):

1. going to the Files tab in lower right pane of R Studio and clicking More -> Set as Working Directory.
2. Opening a (new) project in the folder of interest.
3. Using the `here` package.

If you do not wish to change your working directory, you could as well add an absolute path to the folder the files are located in (like `"H:/My Documents/MyR/Zl0d.dat"`) or a relative path (like `"../MyR/Zl0d.dat"`, in case your current working directory is something like `"H:/My Documents/MyPython"`)